# Wrong Xamarin Forms Image Dimension

Tags: android, image, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to show a 60*60 pixel png image in my Xamarin Forms based Android project using Visual Studio 2013 and the latest Xamaring version.

I followed these steps:

- Located the png image in the Resources\Drawable folder.
- Set the 'Build Action' of the image to AndroidResource
- Created the Xamarin.Forms.Image object as follows:

> ```
>     protected static Image CreateHeaderLeftImage()
>     {
>         Image image = new Image();
>
>         image.Source = Device.OnPlatform(null, ImageSource.FromFile("image.png"), null);
>
>         image.WidthRequest = 60;
>         image.HeightRequest = 60;
>
>         image.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
>         image.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
>
>         return image;
>     }
> ```

- In the App.GetMainPage() I simply set the Content of the main page to the created image

> ```
> public static Page GetMainPage()
> {
>     ContentPage contentPage = new ContentPage();
>
>     contentPage.Content = CreateHeaderLeftImage();
>
>     return contentPage;
> }
> ```

The image appears in the middle of the page with doubled height and doubled width! I did I screenshot of the page and measured the image, it is 120 * 120 instead of 60 * 60!

I reused the code above from many Xamarin examples!

Why is the image enlarged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms doesn't use pixels to size view-elements.

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18255/coordinate-units

So you're not specifying something to be 60px, but in case of Android to be 60dpi.